# Qt C++ Desktop Widget: Keeping Screen Warmness Effects on Entire Screen

Tags: windows, qt, winapi

I am developing a desktop application on Qt and I am trying to click a button that increases your screen warmness and then reset it back to normal when you click the button again. It works while the Qt application (a small GUI with buttons) is in "focus", but once I minimize it or click on another window, my screen warmness goes back to normal; I want the effects to stay whether or not the Qt application is in "focus."

I am using [SetDeviceGammaRamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdevicegammaramp) and the documentation states that the gamma ramp can be "reset at any point" by another application or the OS. However, other people on the internet seem to have success with globally making their screen a different color (for example, [redshift](https://github.com/jonls/redshift)).
I am not sure if this is an API problem or a QT problem.

```
void AdjustScreenColorTemperature()
{
    // 3-colors with 256 intensities array.
    WORD GammaArray[3][256];
    HDC hGammaDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
    WORD wBrightness;

    ::GetDeviceGammaRamp(hGammaDC, GammaArray);

    wBrightness = 100; // Adjust brightness
    for (int ik = 0; ik < 256; ik++) {
        int iArrayValue = ik * (wBrightness + 128);
        if (iArrayValue > 0xffff)
        {
            iArrayValue = 0xffff;
        }
        GammaArray[0][ik] = (WORD) iArrayValue;
        GammaArray[1][ik] = (WORD)(iArrayValue * 0.8); // Green channel (slightly reduced)
        GammaArray[2][ik] = (WORD)(iArrayValue * 0.6); // Blue channel (further reduced)
    }

    ::SetDeviceGammaRamp(hGammaDC, GammaArray);
    ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hGammaDC);
}
```

Above is my current code to adjust screen temperature. Again, it works when my Qt application is "in focus", but I want the screen warmness to persist even when I minimize the application or move to another window or tab on Chrome.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *I am not sure if this is an API problem or a QT problem.* Test the code in a console application... like [redshift](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/blob/490ba2aae9cfee097a88b6e2be98aeb1ce990050/src/redshift.c#L1101) does.

Comment: Or you can use `SetVCPFeature` with VCP code = 0x72 for Gamma. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1328227/why-does-getdevicegammaramp-always-return-false for more information.